# Motorola Atrix mb860 and xe5

Tags: android, delphi, sdk, delphi-xe5

We have two Android phones:

- Samsung Galaxy S4,  Android 4.3
- Motorola Atrix 4g, Android 4.1.2

We made a blank apk from delphi xe 5 update 2 and we installed latest version of sdks. After the installation we plugged Samsung and Motorola phones to the pc. At the xe5 platform menu Atrix mb860 and Samsung phone came. If we compile the apk with Samsung phone it is installing and running with no problem, but when we try it with Atrix it finishes compiling, installs the apk but the app is not woking. It gives an error:

```
`"Project Project1.apk raised exception class Illegal instruction (4)."`.
```

How can we solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Atrix has an NVidia Tegra 2 CPU, which Delphi does not support at this time.  Tegra does not support NEON.  On mobile devices, Delphi supports only ARMv7 CPUs with NEON.  This is documented:

[Android Requirements](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/FireMonkey_Platform_Prerequisites#Android_Requirements)

> RAD Studio supports the development of applications for Android devices running on an ARMv7 processor with NEON support.

[Android Devices Supported for Application Development](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Android_Devices_Supported_for_Application_Development) (Embarcadero DocWiki)

> **Notes:** RAD Studio does not support the following:
>   - Honeycomb (Android 3.x)
>   - Gingerbread emulator
>   - **Tegra 2 devices (NEON support is required)**

Also see:

[Android Devices Supported for Application Development](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Android_Devices_Supported_for_Application_Development) (Delphi Wiki)

Answer (score 0):

To support the a wide range of Android devices you need to use a development tool that can target that the hardware of those devices. As Remy said, the device you are looking at uses hardware other than ARMv7. Which means that Delphi cannot target it.

So far as I know, there are no plans from Embarcadero to support other Android hardware.

> How can we solve this?

You need to use a different development tool. Quite a drastic solution. A good choice would be the native Android development tools. An alternative would be RemObjects Oxygene which may support that hardware and that older Android SDK.